# Progressively Measurable for Right Continuous Adapted Processes

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, self-learning, stochastic-analysis

> Any adapted and ***right continuous*** process $X_t$ is progressively measurable.

For the above statement, I found proof in several books. They all have similar argument as follows. For a given $t > 0$ and $n \in \mathbb N$, define the following funciton sequence 
$$
X_n(s) := X \left( \frac{(k+1)t}{2^n} \right), \ \ \mathrm{if} \ \frac{kt}{2^n} <s\leq \frac{(k+1)t}{2^n}.
$$
It is clear that $X_n$ is ***left continuous***. ***My question is why use left continuous functions to approximate right continuous function, please? Or maybe it does not matter?*** At the beginning, I thought it is typo. However, all proof I read defines $X_n$ to be left-continuous. Thank you!.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To see the point,

Let's fix $t>s>0$ we want to prove that $\lim _{n\to \infty}X_n(s)=X(s)$.

Observe that $$X_n(s)= X(t_{k^{n}+1})$$ where $$k^n=\inf_{k\geq 0} \{k.t/2^n>s\}$$

The point here is that $t_{k^n+1}$ is decreasing to $s$. So that $\lim _{n\to \infty}X_n(s)=\lim _{n\to \infty} X(t_{k^n+1})=X(s)$ because $X$ is right continuous.

If you had taken the following right continuous versions of the dicretization :

$$X_n(s) := X \left( \frac{(k+1)t}{2^n} \right), \ \ \mathrm{if} \ \frac{kt}{2^n} \leq s< \frac{(k+1)t}{2^n}$$

Then the process is not progressively mesurable (it is "looking" into the future at times $s=kt/2^n$)

If alternatively you chose :

$$X_n(s) := X \left( \frac{kt}{2^n} \right), \ \ \mathrm{if} \ \frac{kt}{2^n} \leq s< \frac{(k+1)t}{2^n}$$

Then this one is progressively measurable but $\lim_{n\to \infty} X_n(s) =X(s^-)$ (left continuous limit of $X$) because the equivalent of $t_{k^n+1}$ is increasing to $s$ in this case. So $X_n$ doesn't converge to $X$ at discontinuity point of the trajectory.

Best regards

Comment: That is very thorough explanation. Thank you!

Comment: dear @TheBridge, thank you for the answer! I think it is analogous to the problem I have, but I still can not to repeat your calculations, I do not see how the $X({t_{k^n+1}}) \to X(s)$. Could you please clarify what you mean in $k^n=inf\{...\}$ and what $X({t_{k^n+1}})$ means?

Comment: This comes from the definition of $X_n(s)$ which is $X_n(s) := X \left( \frac{(k+1)t}{2^n} \right), \ \ \mathrm{if} \ \frac{kt}{2^n} <s\leq \frac{(k+1)t}{2^n}$. Using the notation $k^n=\inf_{k\geq 0} \{k.t/2^n>s\}$ means that $k^n$ is actually a function of $s$, this allows to fix $s$ and see what happens as $k^n$ is ocnverging downward to $s$. Is is clearer ? Regards

Comment: Dear @TheBridge, unfortunately, not clearer =) it is the first time I see such notation: $X(t_{k^n+1})$. Do you mean by $k^n$ - a $k$ raised to a power $n$? Moreover do you mean by infimum this: $\inf_{k\geq0}\{k | \frac{t}{2^n}>s\}$; I am a bit unfamiliar with the dot you put between $k$ and inequality. Finally, $X_n(s) := X(\frac{(k+1)t}{2^n}) = X(\frac{kt}{2^n} + \frac{t}{2^n}) = X(t_{k^n+1})$ where I see that second part of the argument converges to 0 as $n\to\infty$,  and the part $\frac{kt}{2^n} \stackrel{? how ? }{\to} s $ obviously should converge, but I do not really understand.

Comment: That's because it is not kt/2^n that converges to s it is k^n(s).t/2^n (making the depedency of k^n in s explicit). as you can "see"  from the very definition of k^n, k^n(s).t/2^n> s no matter what the value of n. and k^n>k^(n+1) this one is left for  you to prove. So now we know that this sequence converges. So is this limit eequal to s ? Le's suppose it is not, then I let you prove that for any such limit s'>s, you can build with your 2 hands a integer n_0 for which any n>n_0, is such that s'>t.k^n/2^n and that's a contradiction so "s" is the limit. Regards